# serial line command parsing

Tags: c, embedded

I'm quite new to C and programming in general, I tried to implement
a simple command parser function, which should do the following:

Read characters from the serial line and parse for the string "boot\n".
If I receive this command I would like to output the name of the application over the serial line.
For the command "boot AppName\n", I would start the application with the name given in AppName.
How can I achieve this with a quite simple parser, by simple I mean in code complexity?

```
static void parse_input(void)
{
    uint16_t i;
    char input_buf[30];
    char c;

    read_character(&c);
    if (c == '\n') /* sync character */
        for (i=0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            read_character(&c);
            input_buf[i] = c;
        }
    /* check for string "boot" in input buffer */
    /* maybe string compare? */
}
```

Thx

Comment: This makes a lot of risky and unnecessary assumptions.  Think how it would fail if you get multiple newlines, or even multiple boot\n messages, or a boot\n followed by something else which might get stuck half in and half out of your buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're working with a fixed size input buffer, I'd simply settle for something like:

```
fflush(stdout);
if ((fgets(input_buf, 30, stdin)) == NULL)
{
    puts("No input...");
    return;
}
if ((strncmp(buffer, "boot", 4)) != 0)
{//boot was NOT found
    printf("Command: %s is unknown\n", buffer);
    return;
}
//boot was found, so something like:
char *token = strtok(buffer, " \n");
while(token != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    if (token) printf("To boot -> %s\n", token);
}
```

The latter is just simply *"chunking"* the string using spaces as a delimiter. so token will point to `boot` after the first call, and then it'll point to whatever *words* (if any) that follow.

Of course, an easier way would be to do

```
char *boot_what = buffer+5;
buffer[4] = '\0';
```

But this implies that the first 5 chars of the buffer are indeed `'b''o''o''t'' '`, the easiest way to obtain this is by doing:

```
char *boot_ptr = strstr(buffer, "boot ");
```

because `strstr` returns a pointer to where the string-to-find is found in the given string... ah well, play around with the functions in `<string.h>` and find what works best for your purpouse.

Comment: Thx for the help! Your code is quite simple and doesn't use lot if's and switch statements!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is using a state machine as follows:

- Take a integer variable `state` initially equal to `0` denoting no character found.
- This variable will be the condition for a `switch` statement
- For case `0`: keep scanning characters until you find `'b'`, where you will update `state` to `1`
- For case `1`, likewise, you will be searching for `'o'`, if you encounter any other character then reset the `state` to `0`.
- Similarly for `'o'` and `'t'`
- Whatever follows after `"boot"` will be your AppName.

Answer (score 1):

The another way for getting serial data and parse as follows i have modified your code

```
static void parse_input(void)
{
    uint16_t i;
    char input_buf[30];
    char c;
    char cmdBuf[ 1024 ];    /* character input buffer */

    int bufPos = 0;

    memset(cmdBuf,0, 1024);
    for(;;) 
    {
        read_character(&c);
        if( ( c == '\r') || ( c == '\n' ) ) 
        {
          if( ( 1 + bufPos ) < 1024 ) {
                cmdBuf[bufPos++] = '\0';
            }

            if(cmdBuf[0] != 0)
            {
                //serial data available in cmdBuf
                //here your code what to do
               //whether you application or other stuff

            }

            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            if( c == '\b' ) 
            {
                if( bufPos > 0 ) {
                    bufPos--;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if( ( 1 + bufPos ) < 1024 ) {
                    cmdBuf[bufPos++] = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Erm, why the busy loop? where does `c` get its value? why `strcpy`? why `cmdBuf[0] != 0` when it's impossible (`cmdBuff[1024] = " ";` <--)? why `break` at the end of an if branch, and still bother with an `else`? I'm sorry, but I fail to see what you're trying to do here

Comment: just edited code....find from where getting value of c.Also `if` for process on finalize buffer (when user hit enter then it execute and break busy loop) and `else` is for store character in `cmdBuff` untill user hit enter.Also `strcpy` used for just taking copy it not require i comment it in code also. And `cmdBuf[0] != 0` condition for if user hit enter with out entering any input.May this clarify you.

Comment: I sort of got what you want to do from the off, but your `else` branch doesn't call `get_character`, so it'll just keep on adding the same char to the buffer. If the `strcpy` call is optional, please don't include it in your example code, because all it does there is add overhead, and the entire point about the `cmdBuff[0]` check is simply this: you only need do it once, not n times... a `while(c = getchar())` loop would make your code a lot easier to read, maintain and generally use it as a starting point.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem Thanks for your suggestion have removed `strcpy()` because it's optional.Now regarding `else` part it get value `c` from `read_character(&c)` function which continuously call from `for..loop`. so any character comes from `read_character(&c)` then this character just added in `cmdbuff`.

Comment: nips, overlooked the fact that `read_character` was _inside_ the loop :)

Comment: you shall check bufPos for overflows to ensure the system will not be overflow at any time!

Comment: @Sven have condition `if( ( 1 + bufPos ) < 1024 ) {...}` already.

Comment: Sure, but what happens if one will add 1025 times a '\n'? The code will overwrite the buffer and then continue to overwrite additional memory after the buffer.